# Where has gone getItem() method?

Tags: java, android, methods, android-recyclerview

Making `RecyclerView` `Adapter class` and dont know why `getItem()` method is missing.

My adapter class:

```
package com.example.pc.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter .MyHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter (Cursor mCursor) {
        this.mCursor = mCursor;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        return new MyHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
        //here all my life i ussed the getItem() method, but now it is missing


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }


    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView tv1, tv2;

        public MyHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            tv2= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

In ScreenShot you can see that there are `getItemCount()`, `getItemId(position);`, and `getItemViewType(position);`, but no `getItem(position)` .

[CLICK FOR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUlAn.png)

Can someone explane me what is happening?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your getItem() method in your code?

Comment: I dont think there ever was a getItem() in recyclerview adapter. Get item would be associated to your list of items which is not associated the your adapter. You are using a cursor for your recyclerview and there really isnt a way to use a cursor with a recyclerview right now

Comment: Sorry for confusión, that is wrong, i forgot to type this method, i feel like brainless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BaseAdapter` which extends `Adapter` and is usually used with `ListView` have an abstract method called `getItem(int position)` which should be implemented in your concrete Adapter class.

[`abstract getItem(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int))

`RecyclerView.Adapter` does not have an `abstract getItem(int)` method. So, you can't override it...

[RecyclerView.Adapter class.. There's no getItem(int) method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

If you need retrieve the item in a specific position, you can create the method by yourself.. Just add the code that you mentioned in the other answer:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter .MyHolder> {

      public Model getItem(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= getItemCount()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item position is out of adapter's range");
        } else if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return new Model (mCursor);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was missing:

```
  public Model getItem(int position) {
    if (position < 0 || position >= getItemCount()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item position is out of adapter's range");
    } else if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return new Model (mCursor);
    }
    return null;
}
```